# PostgreSQL without installation running in Windows but server not starting in CentOS Linux

Tags: postgresql

I have downloaded the windows version of PostgreSQL from here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload

I unzipped it and I executed the commands below to run the server, and it worked in Windows 10:

```
D:\postmaster_standalone\postgresql-11.0-2-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql\bin>initdb -D C:/Users/myuser/pgdataTest -U postgres -E UTF8

D:\postmaster_standalone\postgresql-11.0-2-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql\bin>pg_ctl -D C:/Users/myuser/pgdataTest start
waiting for server to start....2018-11-20 23:06:37.912 IST [14540] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2018-11-20 23:06:37.912 IST [14540] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2018-11-20 23:06:38.231 IST [11352] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-11-20 23:05:02 IST
2018-11-20 23:06:38.385 IST [14540] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started

D:\postmaster_standalone\postgresql-11.0-2-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql\bin>psql -U postgres
psql (11.0)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

In my CentOS , I checked with `uname -m command` and it returns x86_64.
From the above link I downloaded the binaries for version 10.6 of Linux x86-64.

Then, I executed similar steps as in Windows in the below order, but the server is not starting:

```
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ initdb -D /home/cloudera/pgdata -U postgres -E UTF8 
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "cloudera".
This user must also own the server process.
-----
-----
The database cluster will be initialized with locale en_US.UTF-8.
Success. You can now start the database server using:

    postgres -D /home/cloudera/pgdata
or
    pg_ctl -D /home/cloudera/pgdata -l logfile start

[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ pg_ctl -D /home/cloudera/pgdata/ start
server starting
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ psql 
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ psql -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Am I making any mistake? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL binary you are using must use a changed default value for `unix_socket_directories`, and the user that starts the server doesn't have permissions to write there.

Either edit `/home/cloudera/pgdata/postgresql.conf` and set

```
unix_socket_directories = /tmp
```

or start the server with

```
pg_ctl -D /home/cloudera/pgdata/ -o '-k /tmp' start
```

To connect, use

```
psql -h /tmp -U postgres -d postgres
```

Comment: It is still not working and failing with below error: I edited the postgresql.conf file as you suggested. Then ran below steps:
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ pg_ctl -D /home/cloudera/pgdata  -o '-k /tmp' start
server starting
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ psql -h /tmp
psql: FATAL:  database "cloudera" does not exist
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$

Comment: Then use the `-U` and `-d` options to `psql` as indicated in my updated answer.

Comment: It starts using -U and -d options to psql. But unlike windows while running pg_ctl it does not display host and port information as: listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432 . So while connecting to the database through Perl I do not have the host and port information of the postgresql server. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's a completely different problem, right?

Comment: Right, that's the reason I pasted the entire screen shots while running it from windows. I need to know the host and port number. otherwise it is difficult to work with it.

Comment: You can *always* use 127.0.0.1 and port 5432.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 and 5432 not working, I am wondering after firing pg_ctl it never says 'server started..done '. Only saying server starting. Not sure if I am missing something. I also tried lsof command but of no help.  Thanks

Comment: Did you try `::1` as address? You should first figure out if your server is running or not. Look at the log file.

Comment: my server is running and I am able to create sample tables by running the psql command you mentioned. what is ::1 , should I use that instead of 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Ok, I am confused. One comment ago you said it was not working... If it is working for you, let's stop the discussion.

Comment: actually sometimes I am able to get into the command prompt and create table using the psql command you mentioned and sometimes not. But both the times the pg_ctl is printing server is starting. Thanks